How to make a button go to a random page? - fixed so now to keep as solved idk what going
I'm trying to make a button that goes to a random page of the website. I have the code below.
Thanks.
<section class="Banner">
  <div class="banner-content"></div>
  <h1>Homepage</h1>
  <p>Discover new cars from Legendary Brands such as Ferrari, Mercedes or Your One and Only Bugatti</p>
  <a class="randomLink" id="randomLink" href="">Click here!</a>
</section>

const pages = [
    "Mercedes.html",
    "Ferrari.html",
    "Bugatti.html",
];

const randomLink = document.getElementById("randomLink");

randomLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default anchor behavior

    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length);
    const randomPage = pages[randomIndex];

    window.location.href = randomPage; // Redirect to the random page
});



i am new to this so expect very bad mistakes :)

Are you getting an error?

well not exactly i think, im doing this on glitch.com for my website project which is due tmrw and it doesn't work.

well so basically its this https://carsmanic.glitch.me/ if u wanna check it out

https://carsmanic.glitch.me/Ferrari.html https://carsmanic.glitch.me/Mercedes.html https://carsmanic.glitch.me/Bugatti.html thats why i put in Ferrari.html, Mercedes.html and Bugatti.html in the Pages array i was thinking it might go to that

You are attaching the event before the element is rendered. So the click won't work

so where do it put it then below it?

please guide me through, i think i have limited comment thingy :'( noooooo

Ignore what I said, you have defer attribute. The reason could be because other errors in the page that break the script. See console for error. You can always edit your question

@Bill AFAIK there's no limit to commenting on your own question.

here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/carsmanic

I FIXED it i put it in index.html as 